# How to fix blurred text on an iPhone 6 (+)

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

We use a custom font face and custom font sizes in our application.
When running the application on an iPhone 6 (haven't tried 6+ yet but I assume it's the same) all fonts look blurry. We also have an internal tool that uses the system font and it looks blurry as well.

Why is that and what is the right approach to get them to render as crisp as they do on an iPhone 5?

Comment: Is your app scaling or do you have native support for the larger iPhone 6/6+ screen sizes?

Comment: @rmaddy: that was it, thank you, I had no idea that was an option.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your labels or drawing points aren't on an exact pixel, but instead on a fractional pixel. To prevent such situations use methods like ceilf(), floorf() and CGRectIntegral().