# iphone 5 UI Fonts and Images look blurry in iphone6 and iphone 6 plus UI

Tags: ios, fonts, blur

In my projects there are around 100 screens and I have made it for iPhone 5 UI, all are working and look proper in iPhone 5 UI and for iPhone 6 and 6 plus I am using same storyboard and auto scaling working for that. Issue I am facing that fonts and images which are scaled in iPhone 6 and 6 plus look slight blurry then it look in iPhone 5 UI. Is there any method or way where I can show font and images perfect for iPhone 6 and 6 plus UI as well using single storyboard which made in iPhone 5. If anyone have any solution to make it perfect please guide. screens are many, I do not want to create separate storyboard for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus as there are many screen in project. Help is very much appriciatable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there,

Look at this post :

[How to fix blurred text on an iPhone 6 (+)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26288350/3844377)

First comment :

> Is your app scaling or do you have native support for the larger iPhone 6/6+ screen sizes? –  rmaddy

Comment: what is the meaning of native support for the larger iPhone 6/6+. Can you please elaborate this thing ?  My App is properly working in iPhone 6 and 6+ simulator. Only there is slightly blurry which make App UI little I'mproper then the perfect one.

Comment: You can take a look at this tutorial :
http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/

Comment: I have used iPhone 5 screens size to create UI but it cut it off in iPhone 6 and plus, Do I need to use auto resize as well ? because without LaunchScreen it is scaling in all the devices but using LaunchScreen screens are cutting down, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3x size images to display it proper in iPhone6 and 6+ and put it in `Images.xcassets` with new `ImageSet`
i.e. Dimensions 725 × 205 pixels for Resolution 72 pixels/inch (@3x size)