# iPhone 6: Text is blurry in WebView wrapper app. Looks great in website/Safari

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have an iOS app that basically shows the website inside a webview. On the iPhone 6/6+, the text is blurry when viewed in the app, but looks great when viewed as a regular webpage in Safari. Everything is basically the same in the app and website: same CSS rules, etc., and:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have seen this [How to fix blurred text on an iPhone 6 (+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288350/how-to-fix-blurred-text-on-an-iphone-6), but there's just a comment saying to "add native support." Another answer mentioned to add a new launch image. Is that going to fix blurry text? I'm also not sure where this would be added.

It would be a huge plus if this can be fixed in the HTMl/JS/CSS as opposed to making an update to the native wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app isn't built to support the iPhone 6/6 Plus, then it will emulate an iPhone 5, and just scale things up.

So, yes, you should build an submit a new version of the app, built against the latest iOS SDK, with a launch screen.